# Repeating keys with SQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

We have a table in Access (or SQL) which has a system key that is NOT unqiue

There is a column in the same table that needs to have an auto incrementing value, BUT only for each record of the same ID. For the next ID, the auto increment needs to start at one again.

e.g

```
System Key                        IncrementingField
1                                                              1
1                                                              2
1                                                              3
1                                                              4
2                                                              1
2                                                              2
2                                                              3
3                                                              1
3                                                              2
3                                                              3
4                                                              1
5                                                              1
5                                                              2
```

I am being asked to write a function or statement or something to do this but I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: is this for sql server or access ?

Comment: Well, ideally, something that works in both

Comment: Are you even using SQL Server?  Nothing in your question actually suggests that you are.  Is this a 100% MS Access question?  Bear in mind that Access and SQL Server are different applications that both have their own version of SQL running the queries.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with an appropriate partition:

```
row_number() over (partition by [System Key] order by [System Key]) AS [IncrementingField]
```

Here's a sample script:

```
declare @tbl table ([System Key] int)
insert @tbl values (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)
    , (2), (2), (2)
    , (3), (3), (3)
    , (4)
    , (5), (5)

select *
, row_number() over (partition by [System Key] order by [System Key]) as IncrementingField
from @tbl
```

Comment: I can't seem to make the ROW_NUMBER() work since it keeps saying it needs an ORDER BY statement on the OVER clause so I'm considering using a WHILE loop and stored procedure

Comment: @wrichards0 Can you show me your `ROW_NUMBER()` code?

Comment: select SystemKey
      ,row_number() over (partition by SystemKey) as IncrementingField
      ,row_number() over (partition by SystemKey order by SomeCol) as OrderedIncrementingField
from running_numbers

I got Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.

Comment: @wrichards0 Well, you have a `ROW_NUMBER()` without an `ORDER BY`. The only way for this to work is to use a `ORDER BY`. Please use my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you inserting into a SQL Server table, you can create incrementing values using windowed functions:

```
select SystemKey
      ,row_number() over (partition by SystemKey) as IncrementingField
      ,row_number() over (partition by SystemKey order by SomeCol) as OrderedIncrementingField
from Table
```

If you need to 'seed' this value with the previous incrementing value for that ID you can join to your destination table on the SystemKey using a derived table:

```
with MaxInc as
(
    select SystemKey
          ,max(IncrementingField) as MaxIncrementingField
    from Destination
)
select s.SystemKey
      ,row_number() over (partition by s.SystemKey)
        + isnull(d.MaxIncrementingField,0) as IncrementingField
from Source s
    left join MaxInc d
        on(s.SystemKey = d.SystemKey)
```

If this gives you the result set that you need, you can then use this to do your insert.